# Where to find P2pool networks.py settings for altcoins?

Tags: p2pool, altcoin

Is there a forum post or website where all the altcoin networks.py settings are being shared? I can see the P2pool forks on Github where people commit their own networks.py settings back to their own repository but none are being merged back into the original forrestv/p2pool repository. For now, I am specifically searching for the Digibyte altcoin but would like to add the other altcoins later on as well.

I am talking about this part:

```
    litecoin=math.Object(
    PARENT=networks.nets['litecoin'],
    SHARE_PERIOD=15, # seconds
    CHAIN_LENGTH=24*60*60//10, # shares
    REAL_CHAIN_LENGTH=24*60*60//10, # shares
    TARGET_LOOKBEHIND=200, # shares
    SPREAD=3, # blocks
    IDENTIFIER='e037d5b8c6923410'.decode('hex'),
    PREFIX='7208c1a53ef629b0'.decode('hex'),
    P2P_PORT=9 338,
    MIN_TARGET=0,
    MAX_TARGET=2**256//2**20 - 1,
    PERSIST=True,
    WORKER_PORT=9327,
    BOOTSTRAP_ADDRS='...'.split(' '),
    ANNOUNCE_CHANNEL='#p2pool-ltc',
    VERSION_CHECK=lambda v: True,
    VERSION_WARNING=lambda v: 'Upgrade Litecoin to >=0.8.5.1!' if v < 80501 else None,
),
```

And if none are being shared publicly, how do I edit the settings myself for the different altcoins?

Comment: https://github.com/TheBlueMatt/p2pool Have u seen this p2pool software, It has enhanced a few sets of features, Added extra alt coins... Using now runs the same as forrests p2pool but reduces stales & orphans.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this fork https://github.com/Rav3nPL/p2pool-rav It has a lot of altcoins on it.

Comment: i think you can email to the author. sure he is happy to add digikey

Comment: I already did, they have now idea what the correct settings are at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer and posted it here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=214512.msg4998082#msg4998082

Comment: We consider link only answers to be very low quality. It would be much better, if you posted your findings here as well.